# Define new compile-time constant in C# (for #if)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a new constant so I can use it in a similar way as the DEBUG constant:

```
#if(DEBUG)
    public void LoadProcedure ()
#else
    private void LoadProcedure ()
#endif
```

That works for Debug / Release configurations in Visual Studio 2008, but what I need is a TDD or TESTING constant. I created a new build configuration named "Testing". Now the question is how I define that.

Must be some command line parameter ::- ).

Thank you in advance ::- ).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the Project Properties window, Build tab, there is a textbox that lets You enter 1 or more values:

Conditional Compilation Symbols: [TESTING;DEMO         ]

As you will see it is bound to the Configuration selection.

Comment: *laugh*, who would've thought ::- D. I thought that the textbox is for some fancy compile instructions which can also be used to define constants. That is what I was asking for. Didn't think it was actually so simple. Although, truth be told, the label "conditional compilation symbols" *should* have been pretty clear. Thank you Henk! ::- ).

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to overlook something.

Comment: One note (for future readers, given this was 11 years ago now :) ): be careful where you use it and how.  I added a constant, but also used DEBUG for this configuration (similar to recommended solution).  If you use an #elif make sure you use you new constant before #DEBUG because it will have both.