# Unknown constant SCALABILITYTESTING

Tags: c#

I have some strange code in a web service.

```
#if SCALABILITYTESTING
Random r = new Random();
#endif
```

I've done a few searches on Google but found nothing useful. The web service is written in C#. The project it is in, has Microsoft Unit Tests.

Obviously, it's saying if this variable is  true then create a new random number, and my guess is that when I run the Microsoft Unit tests then this is triggered.

**I've not seen anything like this before so I'd like to know what it is.**

The only other clue I have is the following bit of code, which is at the very top of the page.

```
//#define SCALABILITYTESTING
#define SOAPSECURITY
#define SOFTWAREFEATURES
```

Visual Studio highlights `#define`.

I don't know if the stackoverflow question below is related and my guess is that this is something similar to the DEBUG and TRACE constants.

[Define new compile-time constant in C# (for #if)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330511/define-new-compile-time-constant-in-c-for-if)

EDIT
I've found these links which seem related.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

Comment: "if the stackoverflow question below is related." - Yes. you can specyfy symbol in Conditional Compilation Symbols field in properties(its for all project) or with #define in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is related and it is similar to DEBUG and TRACE. This is a conditional compilation symbol. These can be defined in the project properties or directly in the code with `#define`.
I assume, that the developer defined it, to change the way his tests or the code itself worked to simulate multiple users accessing the web service at once - or similar.

Comment: Thanks for this. Your comments match how the service is being used and what I think the developer's reasoning was.

Answer (score 1):

These are *Conditional Compilation Symbols* and are defined in section 9.5 of the [C# Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf). As the name implies, it allows you to omit certain sections of code from being compiled if certain compilation symbols are defined or not defined.

From the spec:

> A conditional compilation symbol has
>   two possible states: defined or
>   undefined. At the beginning of the
>   lexical processing of a source file, a
>   conditional compilation symbol is
>   undefined unless it has been
>   explicitly defined by an external
>   mechanism (such as a command-line
>   compiler option). When a #define
>   directive is processed, the
>   conditional compilation symbol named
>   in that directive becomes defined in
>   that source file. The symbol remains
>   defined until a #undef directive for
>   that same symbol is processed, or
>   until the end of the source file is
>   reached. An implication of this is
>   that #define and #undef directives in
>   one source file have no effect on
>   other source files in the same
>   program.
>
> The name space for conditional
>   compilation symbols is distinct and
>   separate from all other named entities
>   in a C# program. Conditional
>   compilation symbols can only be
>   referenced in #define and #undef
>   directives and in pre-processing
>   expressions.